# android textsize dimen resource link changes to the value

Tags: android

I have added textsize attribute to the button as follows

```
android:textsize="@dimen/button_size"
```

but if i close the content_mail.xml file and then reopen it, it automatically changes to

```
android:textsize="17dp"
```

as i have the size for button_size as 17dp in dimens.xml file.
How to fix this?

Comment: Can you a bit elaborate what is the main issue either you can`t able to change to dimens.xml or anything else you want to do ?

Comment: font size should be in `sp` not in `dp`

Comment: are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Android Studio , it doesn't change to "17sp" , Android Studio show you a "preview" of value from dimen.xml in grey color. If you click the value you will see "@dimen/button_size".

Answer (score 0):

It from the IDE it shows you the actual values referred to by the property. double click on it and it will shows you the reference